# What is the meaning of `ATTR{type}=="1"` on udev?

Tags: linux, networking, udev

On getting info on a network device, one of the attributes listed for the top level device is:

```
ATTR{type}=="1"
```

What is the meaning of this and why rules to give persistent names to network devices matches against it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ATTR{type}` designates the value of the corresponding entry in `/sys`, as filtered by the other elements in udev filters. If you do `find /sys/ -name type` you can see it can apply to a large list of objects in various subsystems.

Since you tagged your question with `linux` `networking` I can assume the question is about network devices only, and it's then the [network interface protocol `type`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net?h=linux-4.14.y#n239):

> What:      /sys/class/net/<iface>/type
>   Date:      April 2005
>   KernelVersion: 2.6.12
>   Contact:   netdev@vger.kernel.org
>   Description:
>   Indicates the interface protocol type as a decimal value. See [`include/uapi/linux/if_arp.h`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/if_arp.h?h=linux-4.14.y#n27) for all possible values.

[This file](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/if_arp.h?h=linux-4.14.y#n27) in turn defines known values:

```
#define ARPHRD_ETHER    1       /* Ethernet 10Mbps      */
```

That's the `1` in `ATTR{type}=="1"` and it simply means "Ethernet device" (whatever its speed, be it real including pseudo-ethernet devices like wireless, or virtual, including veth or bridges...).

An other common interface is the `lo` interface with type 772 (so `udev` won't care about it if it ever detected one appearing with the previous `ATTR{type}=="1"`), as seen there:

```
#define ARPHRD_LOOPBACK 772     /* Loopback device      */
```

It can be verified with:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/lo/type
772
```

Comment: Thank you. I was so worried about what would be the value for wireless interface. Now I can peacefully use 1